# How should I inject dependencies to immutable domain objects instantiated by Mybatis?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, mybatis

I'm developing a Spring Boot application and using Mybatis. To ensure immutability of objects instantiated by Mybatis, I make Mybatis use `<constructor>` instead of setters that make objects mutable. Like the other ordinal objects, these Mybatis-instantiated objects need dependencies to accomplish their responsibilities, and these dependencies are sometimes beans instantiated by Spring.

If an object is instantiated by Spring, it's easy to inject dependencies to it. But an object instantiated by Mybatis is, obviously, out of Spring's DI container and you can't use `@Autowired` or other Spring mechanics to inject its dependencies.

Of course I can inject dependencies manually after instantiation by Mybatis like:

```
DomainA d = DomainAMapper.fetchOne();
d.setDependency(dependency);
```

But this breaks immutability of `DomainA`.

How can I satisfy my need i.e. inject dependencies to Mybatis-instantiated objects while keeping their immutability?

Comment: Can you share same examples "dependencies" you would like to manage? For examples, tell me a few dependencies  in DomainA.

Comment: @Rafa Thank you for commenting. I mean dependencies here as the other classes used in DomainA class. In my current situation it's a Java wrapper class of native module written in C++ to deal with machine learning things. I would like to inject it to make unit testing easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are fine with the current design and you are focused on testing, then PowerMockit should attend your needs as it is capable to "set/mock" private members.

Example:

```
@Component
public class DomainA {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;
    public boolean isContextInitilized() {
        return context != null;
    }
}
```

---

```
import org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberModifier;
...    
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class DemoApplicationTests {
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext contextToInject;
    @Autowired
    DomainA domainAAutowired;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        // Autowired spring beans work fine
        assertTrue(domainAAutowired.isContextInitilized());
        // Class out of spring context won't initialize dependencies
        DomainA domainOutOfSpringContext = new DomainA();
        assertFalse(domainOutOfSpringContext.isContextInitilized());
        // We can 'set' private members using PowerMock
        MemberModifier.field(DomainA.class, "context").set(domainOutOfSpringContext, contextToInject);
        assertTrue(domainOutOfSpringContext.isContextInitilized());
    }
}
```

On a side note, MyBatis classes are supposed to be simple POJOs. Having spring dependencies in MyBatis may be an indicator of poor separation of concerns as they should be only concerned with the persistence layer.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. And your opinion that `Having spring dependencies in MyBatis may be an indicator of poor separation of concerns as they should be only concerned with the persistence layer` really makes sense to me. But in that sense, Should Mybatis generated objects have just getters and setters and deligates logic to the other classes? Do you have any ideas how we can avoid [anemic domain model](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html)?

Comment: Think as MyBatis interfaces as `Repositories` and MyBatis classes as `Entities`. Then create a `Service` layer which is a more natural place to contain spring dependencies. The `Service` layer should be thin but capable to delegate to other resources. You can also imagine the `Service` layer as a `Facade` for your resources.

Comment: Thank you again for answering. `The Service layer should be thin but capable to delegate to other resources`. So can this logic flow be a possible example? 1) Service class calls repositories to fetch Entity from DB, 2) Service class calls some factories to instantiate Domain object that contains fetched Entity, 3) Service class calls Domain object's method to execute business logic.

Comment: #1 & #3 sound fine. #2 is hard to say, possibly correct if your service just delegates to the factories. How about if you ask another SOF question with examples for folks to discuss?

Comment: Indeed the discussion will be so long. Thank you very much again for taking your time to answer my questions one after another.